# Pattern searching in Wikipedia dump

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, wikipedia, information-extraction

I'm trying to do some Relation Extraction on a Wikipedia dump.

In order to do so, I need to search patterns in a VERY large XML/JSON file (15 GB compressed, 50 GB uncompressed).

What is the best way to do so? Regular string-matching algorithms? Using ElasticSearch-like technologies? If so, how?

Comment: please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917152/elasticsearch-6-unable-to-install-plugin-org-wikimedia-searchextra-not-compatib/49917389#49917389

Comment: This may interest you : a web service to perform sql queries on wikimedia databases, see https://quarry.wmflabs.org/ and its doc https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Research:Quarry.

Comment: I you only need to search it once, nothing beats a decently implemented substring matching algorithm. If you need to search it often, the overhead of building an index might be worth it.

Comment: Project [wikipedia-to-elastic](https://github.com/AlonEirew/wikipedia-to-elastic) seems similar to what you need, contains a docker image with elasticsearch index created from wikipedia dump (disclosure - I'm the project developer).